# Are any Java Card 3.0 smart cards available?

Tags: java, smartcard

The Java Card 3.0 specification (draft?) came out in 2008. It is now 2013. Are there any existing smart cards that actually implement the specification? How about USB tokens?

The best I've found is Java Card 2.2.2 + ECC functions from 3.0.

If Java Card 3.0 seems dead in the water, are there any good alternatives? A cheap and secure programmable device that can do custom key generation and cryptographic operations inside the device.

Comment: We have JavaCard 3.0.1 Classic currently availible even for smaller projects:
<www.JCOP.MoTechno.com>

Comment: Found one that is on sale publicly: http://www.motechno.com/javacard3.0.html

Answer (score 7):

Found the solution myself.

There is one smart card platform that implements Java Card 3.0.1 Classic, available as a smart card and as a USB token:

- Sm@rtCafé Expert 6.0
- StarSign Crypto USB Token

There also seems to be some similar card from CardLogix.

However, these are all Java Card 3.0 Classic, which is very close to Java Card 2.2.2. The minute differences are easily implemented by card manufacturers, so it seems that most cards will probably update to Java Card 3.0 Classic eventually.

The case for Java Card 3.0 Connected seems a lot bleaker. Nobody has come up with a card, and I couldn't find any information about cards in the making either. It would seem that the requirements are a bit steep for current generation cards and there are not many use cases for such cards.

Unfortunately, even ignoring the HTTP servlet stuff, only Java Card 3.0 Connected edition is the one supporting Java 6 with threads, full types, generics, etc. Java Card 3.0 Classic is still using the 16-bit Java with very few features.

Comment: Of course most smart cards should be JC 3.0.1 or higher by now. Generally you should look at the chip (NXP, Infineon etc.) & card manufacturers (Gemalto, IDEMIA etc) which platforms deliver a specific version of Java Card. The ones mentioned above are from Gieseke and Devrient (usually abrieviated to  G&D).